# js does execute in debugmode but not when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, wordpress, debugging

I added a js via `<script src="http://domain.com/wp-content/themes/Foxy/js/loescheVorschaubild.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script onload="loescheVorschaubild()" src="http://domain.com/wp-content/themes/Foxy/js/loescheVorschaubild.js"></script>` to a page. When I use FF in debug-mode everythings works fine. The debugger stops at the breakpoint and I can get through the code. But without debugging the code doesn't even execute - Btw, the same in Opera.

Since this is on a particular WP-page I can not load the code with other techniques - or I haven't got the right idea yet.

Any hints appreciated - thx
Odido

Thx for reading - I got the answer:

apperently this onload does NOT wait until the whole page is rendered. I moved the code shown above to the end of the page and now it works.